# Users who are logged in more than 2 times - bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, users

I'm trying to write a script that will check if users (as arguments) are logged more than one time simultaneously. So far I have a script then checks the first argument and it works fine. But how do I do it to check for other users as arguments? Here is the code:

```
for users in $(w -h)
do    
if [ "$users" = "$1" ]
then echo "User $1 is logged in"
counter=$((counter+1))
fi
done    
if [ "$counter" > 1 ]
then echo "User $1 is logged $counter times"
else
echo "User $1 is logged less than two times"
fi
```

*bash usersscript.sh user1 user2 user3 etc...*
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To modfy your current approach, you would need an array of counters for the different users, and an additional loop to test each value of `$users` against each positional parameter `$1`, `$2`, ... .

Note that `for users in $(w -h)` loops over all the whitespace-delimited tokens in the output of `w -h`, not just the usernames - it may "work" (because it's unlikely that other tokens match a valid username) but it's not "right" - you could use `$(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1)` to extract just the usernames.

For a simpler approach, you could run `w -h` for each username given on the command line, and count the number of lines of output, for example using `wc -l`

```
#!/bin/sh

for user do

  counter=$(w -h "$user" | wc -l)

  if [ "$counter" -gt 2 ]; then
    printf "user %s is logged in %d times\n" "$user" "$counter"
  else
    printf "user %s is logged in less than two times\n" "$user"
  fi

done
```

Note that `bash` is not necessary for this - you can use the lighter `/bin/sh` shell (although the same code will run in bash).

Comment: Can you tell what it should be to be correct?

Comment: @GSaple you could use `$(w -h | cut -d ' ' -f1)` to extract only the usernames from the `w` output

Comment: `for user do` ?

Comment: @bac0n slightly uncommon these days I know but see [How to use arguments like $1 $2 … in a for loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314041/65304)